# Quartz event every n weeks, on a number of different days

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have an application which needs to fire a quartz event every n weeks (n is given by the user), on more than one day (for example: every monday and tuesday, every 2 weeks). This is the code I wrote:

```
newTrigger()
.withSchedule(DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.dailyTimeIntervalSchedule().onDaysOfTheWeek(daysOfWeek.toArray(new Integer[0]))
.withIntervalInHours(n*7*24))
.startAt(startingDate)
.build();
```

daysOfWeek is a LinkedList containing the days chosen by the user (monday and tuesday, in our example).

However, this thing doesn't work, but it only takes the first selected day (monday) and after a few inserts... it even skips to Sunday. Here is the output info:

`NEXT DATE Mon Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Apr 21 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon May 05 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon May 19 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Jun 02 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Jun 16 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Jun 30 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Jul 14 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Jul 28 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Aug 11 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Aug 25 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Sep 08 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Sep 22 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Oct 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Mon Oct 20 00:00:00 CEST 2014
NEXT DATE Sun Nov 02 00:00:00 CET 2014
NEXT DATE Sun Nov 16 00:00:00 CET 2014
NEXT DATE Sun Nov 30 00:00:00 CET 2014
NEXT DATE Sun Dec 14 00:00:00 CET 2014
NEXT DATE Sun Dec 28 00:00:00 CET 2014`

Please help me understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: This is a Q&A website, not a place where we write workaround for you. That said, in your example the date skips from Monday to Sunday because the 26th of October is the last day of Daylight Saving Time so there is an hour of difference. In your code you are using 7*24 to calculate the hours in a week but that is not always true. In the year there is actually a day with 25 hours and one with 23 (when DST starts and ends).

Comment: hmmm...thanks about DST story! :) I forgot about it. However did you have any ideas why it takes just the first day?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not a quartz expert, but maybe the problem lies in `withIntervalInHours`. I think that this interval is applied on the first date (Mon Apr 07 in your example) and this lead to quartz skipping directly to Mon Apr 21.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like encoding this pattern in a single CronTrigger is not going to work. However, a job can always reschedule itself for execution at a later time. So if a method was added to calculate the next job run, the current execution would schedule the next execution.

For example, if the list of days is on Monday, then the next execution would be Tuesday. Yet on Tuesday, the next execution would be two weeks away on a Monday.